# Увеличение размера раздела с Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gparted

Добрый день, возможно ли увеличить размер раздела с Ubuntu из под нее же с помощью gparted без каких либо потерь?

***Обновление***

Спасибо всем, увеличу когда будет возможность с liveCD

Comment: Увеличить раздел - не вопрос. Только файловая система об этом увеличении ничего знать не будет... В любом случае - бэкапы /etc, хомяков и прочих важных данных сделайте.

Comment: Так а смысл тогда увеличивать, если файловая система ничего знать не будет об этом?

Comment: можно. если раздел не корневой, то проблем практически никогда не бывает. Максимум бывает нужно перезагрузиться. А вот если нужно корневой раздел трогать - лучше загрузиться с liveCD.

Comment: Нужно как раз таки корневой раздел увеличить, и сейчас нет возможности загрузиться с liveCD, из под Ubuntu никак нельзя увеличить?

Comment: Есть обходной вариант. Допустим, нужно увеличить корневой раздел, потому что там есть папка var, которая постоянно переполняется. Создаем отдельный раздел под эту папку (это можно делать на живой системе), копируем туда нужные файлы (тут нужно аккуратно, опять, лучше это все делать с лайвсиди), правим fstab и перезагружаемся (хотя можно и без перезагрузки).

Comment: @KoVadim, *если раздел не корневой* — насколько мне известно, это абсолютно не существенно в данном случае. что существенно — наличие неразмеченного пространства сразу же за этим разделом. если это, конечно, не *logical volume* (для него нет подобного ограничения).